# Parse JSON array response to FlatList in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm willing to parse the above JSON response to a FlatList, but I can't figure what I'm missing. Since it does not have a key and value pair, I'm not sure how to render it.

```html
{"list":["a","b","c","d"]}
```

My code is...

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { dataSource: [] };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('http://.../');
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson.list });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Text>{item[index]}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see a typo here `this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson.lista });`  you don't have any property named `lista` in your json

Comment: Sure! I corrected, but still cant parse.

Comment: Also You don't need to index here `renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Text>{item[index]}</Text>}`  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need item index, try the below code and let me know.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { dataSource: [] };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch('http://.../');
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson.list });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={this.state.dataSource.indexOf(item)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because you're doing the below

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Text>{item[index]]}</Text>}
```

item is referring to a,b,c,d but you're doing `a[index]`,`b[index]` which clearly wrong

**Solutions:**

```
<FlatList
...
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
...
/>
```

You don't need index for your `renderItem` because the `item` is already `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` respectively

Comment: I'll try it so!

Comment: @issac I also think this is your problem. In addition, you could read this article to examine some examples https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6

Comment: @vuluu: Sorry I don't follow you

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ArthurÁvila: Do mark it as answer if it helps to fix your problem as a reference for future reader stumbled on same issue. Glad to help thanks